# Algorithm for finding an entity in a maze without prior knowledge

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search, a-star, maze

I have a grid like weighted maze and I need to find the shortest path to an entity without having any prior knowledge of the maze.

Algorithms like A* expect priot knowledge and 'jump' around when looking around, but that's not possible when I have a robot for example.

My first thought would be to initially explore the whole maze using BFS and then apply A* on the explored to find the shortest considering the weights as well. But that seems naive.

Can anyone point me to some algorithms that could be a good fit for this problem?

Comment: Someone asked basically the same question just the other day: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53121908/238419

Answer (score 0):

I think the most applicable algorithm for this sort of problem would be [Dijkstra's algorithm.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/)

In short, the algorithm starts at some root node, scans all neighbors and choose the node with the shortest path from the root to visit.

A table is kept that contains every node's

- Shortest path from the root
- The last node in the path to get to this node

  The shortest path to a node is updated in the table whenever a shorter path is discovered.
  When your entity is visited, its shortest path will be the shortest path from root->entity, and backtracking through its parents will yield the actual node path.
  (Here's another [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVfj6mxhdMw) if you're confused).